# How to label the object, from the edge detection image?

Tags: image, image-processing

How to label the edges in an image, I have some of the cells that I have applied edge detection techniques. Now I want to label the edge detected cell from an image.

Comment: PS: If you're interested in this sort of question, you might be interested to support [the signal, image and video processing proposal over on Area 51.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1691/signal-image-video-processing?referrer=8sRRWsMYXdMN5QfMOt5KEg2)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to give more information: how well does the edge detection work? Do you get whole blobs, or disconnected, but related, edges?  Posting an example of the sort of image, and the problem would be good --- pictures (images) are worth a thousand words, particularly when describing image processing problems.

[This page might be a start.](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/imgProc/blobDetection.html) It gives the pseudocode:

```
l = 1                              // Initial Label number
for each pixel
  if pixel X is foreground
    if neighbours A,B,C & D are unlabelled (equal to zero)
      label pixel X with l
      increment l
    else
       num = neighbour label A,B,C & D with least value, not including 0
       label pixel X and pixels A, B, C & D if foreground with num
    end if
  end if
done
```